# Cannot create new Web Application in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I'm a Sharepoint Beginner and i have a question :
I setup a Develop machine with there step : IIS, VS 2008, MOSS 2007. 
At first, it works, but i have realized that, i cannot create a new web application :
From Sharepoint Site Administrator/Application Manager/ Create or extend ...
It says that the Web application created successful. But in fact, there's no new Web application created ( I checked it in IIS )
Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting confused between site collections (IIS Web site) - and sites and webs, which are containers inside a site collection which exists in SQL Server and is mapped to the URL of the site collection .. ??

Comment: Sorry about my English. May be, i express not good. 
When i create a new Web application from Sharepoint Site Administrator, it look like everythink works normaly(may be at port 8808 for example). But when i check in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss, there no 8808 folder.

Comment: Hmm. I dont know then is the honest answer. Are you only using one server? Do you have administrator rights? Are there any events in the event log?